# Is it possible to store values from ipywidgets to cell code like Google colab Form

Tags: google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

When I use Google Colab Form and change field value, new value stored in cell code. So next time I open notebook I see new value in cell.
How can I use same functionality for ipywidgets field?

For example.

*Cell with Colab Form:*

```py
slices = 4 #@param {type:"slider", min:1, max:10, step:0}
```

*Cell with ipywidget:*

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

# interact() syntax
def f(x):
    return x

interact(f, x=10);


# classic syntax
widgets.IntSlider(
    value=7,
    min=0,
    max=10,
    step=1,
    description='Test:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d'
)
```

In Google Colab Form changed slider value injects into cell code.
But I didn't find same functionality for ipywidgets. If I move slider - its new value will be lost on notebook reload.

Maybe some tricks exists for this?

Comment: I don't think there is a native way to persist widget state between sessions in `ipywidgets`.

Comment: In jupyterlab at least you can save the widget state via the Settings menu and `Save Widget State Automatically` There is also a PR attempting to make this saving the default which you can see here: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/pull/3114

Comment: Also, @ac24 I've seen  you answering a lot of ipywidgets questions which is awesome. You should know that there's a chat room for ipywdigets here: https://gitter.im/jupyter-widgets/Lobby and that there are bi-weekly dev meetings which *anyone* is welcome to join - if you're interested then people would love to see you there (https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/team-compass/issues/1)